How can I move the cursor to the beginning of the ueiin the address bar of Google chrome browser?
When I try to edit the URL in the address bar in Google chrome browser in android, the cursor is at the end of the URL by default. Can I move the cursor to the beginning of the URL quickly, or even anywhere in the URL? This is helpful especially when the URL has a long list of query strings etc.
